# What does the entry 3/day mean if several spell-like/psi-like abilities are listed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, psionics

I am preparing an encounter involving a psionic Yuan-Ti Abomination. The entry in the XPH lists under the section psi-like abilities:

> 3/day—body purification (6 points*), psionic charm (all targets, 1
>   day/level, DC 19*), concealing amorpha, deeper darkness, mind thrust
>   (ML 7th, 7d10, DC 18*), psionic suggestion (four targets, DC 16*);
>   (XPH, p. 218)

Does that mean the Yuan-Ti can manifest

a) *each* psi-like ability listed here 3/day,

b) a total of three manifestations of abilities in this list, including using the possibility to use one ability three times

c) three abilites out of this list once each

A similar issue arises with the spell-like abilities in the gnome entry in PHB, where it says:

> 1/day—dancing lights, ghost sound, prestidigitation.

Does this mean gnomes can use each of these abilities once, or only one of these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to track down a pure RAW explanation, but gauging by the wording in the description for spell-like abilities [d20srd](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellLikeAbilities)

> A spell-like ability usually has a limit on how often **it** can be used (*emphasis mine*)

It is referring to the specific spell like ability, not spell like abilities in general, therefore one could infer each Sp that listed can be used however many times is specified in the creatures stat block section for special abilities.

Comment: Not to mention we wouldn't really know how many uses per day we could use the rest of the abilities listed.